# Want to remove OEM logo during boot in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04

How do I remove terrible OEM logo during Boot.(In my case it is Sony Viao)Can't find a solution online.Please help

Comment: The OEM logo is only shown when the PC is booted through UEFI mode; it is not shown in Legacy BIOS mode. To hide it you *could* reinstall Ubuntu through Legacy (if supported by your PC).

Comment: @DanielMassey how do I install through legacy ?

Comment: @heynnema it doesn't work I also saw this on the internet. In newest update u can't remove it

Comment: So just leave it

Comment: If you follow my instruction, you can change the OEM logo screen that shows in 20.04, back to the standard Ubuntu logo. Doesn't that work for you? Please show me a screenshot of what you're seeing after you enter the command.

Comment: @DanielMassey In fact it's shown by using the **EFI** framebuffer.Some distributions show the OEM logo via [plymouth daemon](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Plymouth) and some don't.

Comment: Have you set the option **nomodeset** in the kernel command-line ?

Comment: @ParsaMousavi Setting nomodeset would disable the video driver, and potentially mess up screen resolution settings.

Comment: Change plymouth theme.

Comment: Status please... also, please see my updated answer. Please show me a screenshot of what you're seeing after you enter the command.

Answer (score 3):

The OEM logo is definitely controlled by `UseFirmwareBackground=true` in the default Plymouth theme file.

So the most straightforward way is to edit the file via command below, and change the key value to `false` under boot-up, reboot, and shutdown section.

```
sudo nano /usr/share/plymouth/themes/bgrt/bgrt.plymouth
```

After that, you may also use Ubuntu logo in the place (screen center) by manually creating a '`background-tile.png`' image with size of screen resolution, and put it into `/usr/share/plymouth/themes/spinner/` directory.

As the default `bgrt` theme refers to `spinner` with just OEM enabled, user may also install that theme via `update-alternatives --install` command and apply it via the command @heynnema answered.

Tested in Ubuntu 22.04, Ubuntu 22.10 and here the [step by step guide](https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2022/10/replace-manufacturer-ubuntu/).

Comment: Lubuntu : Do the advised modification in /usr/share/plymouth/themes/lubuntu-logo/lubuntu-logo.plymouth and in /usr/share/plymouth/themes/lubuntu-logo/bgrt/bgrt.plymouth

Comment: Other ubuntu versions : go to /usr/share/plymouth/themes (in the terminal) and type 'sudo grep -r UseFirmwareBackground .' (The dot at the end of the line is part of the command). This will show you all lines where you have "UseFirmwareBackground" and whether they are set to "true" or to "false", then you can go and change them if required.

Answer (score 2):

Do this...

In `terminal`:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth
```

[image]

And select a different boot screen.

```
sudo update-initramfs -c -k $(uname -r)
```

Then reboot.