# How to remove laptop manufacturer logo on boot screen

Tags: boot

I want to remove the Lenovo logo of my boot screen as I have a custom plymouth boot "animation". I check the BIOS and I can't find anything. Lenovo support said that I need to use windows to remove it (I don't trust them as they didn't even know what Linux was or how to enter the BIOS). Is this possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Want to remove OEM logo during boot in ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1238754/want-to-remove-oem-logo-during-boot-in-ubuntu-20-04)

Comment: I've done that and it didn't work. I use Plymouth for my boot screen but the Lenovo logo is still there

Comment: I see. BIOS-stored logos are tricky. You could take a look at [this](https://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/How_to_change_the_BIOS_bootsplash_screen) but it sounds risky, as well as a lot of work.

Comment: @user535733 No, OP is correct: the question linked to doesn't change the Lenovo logo that is displayed from the BIOS. It changes a logo that is displayed later on in the boot process.

Comment: @Jos vote retracted, comment cheerfully withdrawn.