I installed over Windows, but I still see Microsoft logo at boot up/down
I still see the Microsoft logo when I power up/down & if I reboot with the volume up button engaged, I still get to the Microsoft BIOS/UEFI screen. Did I not install Ubuntu correctly, or is this normal because I am on a Microsoft Surface laptop?
More info...
I never registered a profile with Microsoft, so I suspect my Windows 11 functionality could've had issues. For example, when I first tried to install Ubuntu, I got stopped by a screen that said I needed to disable BitLocker. But when I went to check that setting, it was never set up. So I had to enable it and then disable it before I was able to install Ubuntu.
I just want to make sure Microsoft's latest update that takes screenshots every few seconds no longer has any access to my laptop. So I'd like to remove all trace of Windows. Is that possible?

Is Ubuntu up and running OK?

You didn't provide details of what Ubuntu product or release you installed; that detail may also help, maybe also clues as to make/model & age of your hardware.

Ubuntu appears to be working perfectly: HARDWARE = Microsoft Corporation Surface Book 2, Memory = 16 GB, Processor = Intel® Core™ i7-8650U × 8, Graphics = Intel® UHD Graphics 620 (KBL GT2),  Graphics 1 = NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060. SOFTWARE Firmware = 394.779.768, OS, Ubuntu 24.04 LTS, 64 bit, GNOME Version = 46, Windowing System = X11, Kernel Version = Linux 6.8.0-31-generic

Not related to the question but relevant for surface devices: If some hardware is not working on Surface devices, check out this repo for drivers https://github.com/linux-surface/linux-surface

"Microsoft's latest update that take screenshots every few seconds" - Wait what?

I think it should be possible to replace the OEM logo with something else if you want to get rid of it – https://askubuntu.com/questions/1238754/want-to-remove-oem-logo-during-boot-in-ubuntu-20-04

Changing plymouth screens (to one that doesn't include the OEM logo) is the easy fix....   When Ubuntu switched to showing the OEM logo many cycles ago, we flavors had to adjust or switch our plymouth logos to show it; as the default from prior cycles didn't show OEM logo

@marcelm  Recall is a W11 preview feature, and appears to be as awful as it sounds.   The only "good news" is that it's apparently limited to the newest arm laptops due to nothing else having a powerful enough accelerator for the Copilot AI BS.    https://www.pcgamer.com/software/windows/windows-ai-feature-takes-screenshots-of-your-desktop-every-few-seconds-and-i-cant-imagine-wanting-that/

@DanIsFiddlingByFirelight there is no actual requirement for an accelerator, this is a marketing requirement only. https://twitter.com/GossiTheDog/status/1797187527821906199

You are likely seeing the image (which includes the Microsoft logo) from the Microsoft Surface laptop's firmware.
I have successfully installed Ubuntu on laptops (that previously had Windows installed) from other manufacturers, and the manufacturer logos appear when the system boots and shuts down.  For those laptops, I re-partitioned and formatted the HDDs/SSDs, so Windows could not be left behind.

This sounds promising. I just detailed all the hardware & software specs above in case that helps you to confirm the answer. Is there a tutorial I can follow  to do what you did to make sure nothing from Windows is left behind on my laptop? Unfortunately I don't know enough to even know what the HDDs/SSDs are lol

No problem.  HDDs/SSDs are just hard disk drives (HDDs) and solid state drives (SSDs).  Modern computers typically use one or the other, or both, to store their data.  Unfortunately, I'm not aware of a tutorial for what I did, but if Ubuntu booted for you, there is no realistic chance that Windows can take any screenshots (even if it was accidentally left behind).

OK thank you - that makes me feel better! I appreciate the help and how quick it came!

Your device is a very good one, and Ubuntu is so efficient that you should now enjoy many years of happy use out of that machine.

You're most welcome. I happened to see your question, and I, too, was concerned the very first time I encountered the same issue. It looks like you are new here, and if so, I'll quickly mention that it is customary to click the up-arrow next to "upvote" any answers you consider to be quality and helpful (for all questions, not just this one!), and to also click the checkmark next to an answer if you want to accept it (only for questions you have asked).  You can always "unaccept" an answer and accept a different answer later on if you change your mind.  Good luck, and welcome!

I managed to accidentally enter the factory test mode on one of my portable monitors and it had the option to select the boot logo between all the different brands, that could be handy here. Maybe the factory who actually makes the surface has something similar. :)
